# How to integrate python tensorflow code with the android studio?

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Basically I have the android application which uses camera feature developed in android studio and on the other hand I have my tensorflow code written in python that i want to link with the android work.

Is there a way to achieve this??? I figured out bazel and cmake but not much of information is on the google

Comment: What was the problem with **bazel**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the your answer?↓
https://qiita.com/tchkwkzk/items/aa481db14126b6abdaa1

Sorry.This page is written by Japanese.
Because I can't use English well, I can't translate Japanese into English.
Please translate the homepage.

Comment: Either provide a concrete usable answer, or share a link via the comments (preferably in the same language as the question).

Comment: oh,sorry. I'll be more careful. Namely, I delete this answer, didn't I?

Comment: You can always edit it with the right answer and then provide a link for further reading. If you feel you cannot adequately answer the question then maybe it's best to delete it.

I can understand your trouble translating. If you know the solution perhaps you can just provide the code. StackOverflow is all about fixing problems :)